# Solving questions using cylindrical method

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the volume of a solid using the cylindrical method. The region it is bounded is found below. I have came up with some answers for different situations and would like to know if my approach is correct before i integrate further.
$$y=x^{0.5}$$
$$x=4$$
$$x=0$$
[image]
a)rotation around the x-axis
$$V=2\pi\int_0^2 (y)(4-y^{2})dy$$
b)rotation around y-axis
$$V=2\pi\int_0^4 (x)(x^{0.5})dx$$
c)rotation around line y=3
$$V=2\pi\int_0^2 (3-y)(4-(y^{2}))dy$$
d)rotation around line x=5
$$V=2\pi\int_0^4 (5-x)(x^{0.5})dx$$

Now instead of x=4, replace with y=2
$$y=x^{0.5}$$
$$y=2$$
$$x=0$$
a)rotation around the x-axis
$$V=2\pi\int_0^2 (y)(y^{2})dy$$
b)rotation around y-axis
$$V=2\pi\int_0^4 (x)(2-x^{0.5})dx$$
c)rotation around line y=3
$$V=2\pi\int_0^2 (3-y)(y^{2})dy$$
d)rotation around line x=5
$$V=2\pi\int_0^4 (5-x)(2-x^{0.5})dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Since the solution below was posted, the question has evolved. Below is the answer to the original question.

I imagine you have drawn a picture. Our region is the finite region bounded by the curves $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=2$, and $x=0$.

a) The integral is not correct. We are rotating about the $x$-axis. A typical cylindrical shell has radius $y$, and "height" $x-0$, that is, $y^2$. So the volume is
$$2\pi \int_0^2 (y)(y^2)\,dy.$$

b) We are rotating about the $y$-axis. A typical cylindrical shell has radius $x$, and height $2-\sqrt{x}$. so the volume is
$$2\pi\int_{0}^{4} (x)(2-\sqrt{x})\,dx.$$

c) We are now rotating about $y=3$. A typical cylindrical shell has radius $3-y$, and height $x-0$, that is, $y^2$. You can now write down the integral.

d) We leave this one to you. Same basic idea.

Comment: for part a i refered to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCMkHkprN0I&noredirect=1   i have currently tried the washer method for part a and b and it gives me the same result as i did for with the cylindrical method.

Comment: I had a couple of typos, fixed.  Now that you have added a picture, it is clear that you have the wrong region. Our region is bounded by the $y$-axis, $y=2$. and the parabola. You have not drawn $y=2$. The region is below $y=2$, and to the **left** of the parabola.

Comment: so what you mean is the region that is shaded grey has nothing to do with finding the volume of it? Rather because of the function being bounded by y=2, i should focus everything outside the curve?

Comment: The problem says that the bounding curves are $x=0$ (the $y$-axis), the line $y=2$, and the parabola. If you look at the rectangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(4,0)$, $(4,2)$, and $(0,2)$, we are rotating the *unshaded* part of the rectangle. We could rotate the shaded part, and remove its volume from the volumes of certain cylinders. But a direct approach is easier, as in the solution above.

Comment: ok understood what you meant. For part d)is this the right answer? $$2\pi\int_{0}^{4} (5-x)(2-\sqrt{x})\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes, that's the right expression. You have good control over the process, the only problem was wrong region.

Comment: i just edited the question with solving y=2. Now i would like to  know since previously i was solving with X=4 with respect to the shaded region. Is my approach correct when it is x=4?

Comment: Yes, for the shaded region the expressions were correct.

Comment: i have a similar question could you take a look? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746569/solids-of-revolution-question